# Using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames to control an image slideshow

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, animation

I'm trying to use an animation to control a slideshow of images.

The user enters a folder path into txtaddress, clicks on btnGo and the program displays each image found in that folder for two seconds.

However, I'm stuggling to control this using animations. When it begins the slideshow I get an error of "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path "imgMain.Source"

My complete code is below. Any ideas?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Class MainWindow

    Private Property ImageSource As String

    Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        'Get file list
        Dim fileList(0) As String
        Dim btm(0) As BitmapImage
        Dim dir1 As New DirectoryInfo(txtAddress.Text)
        Dim anim As New ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames

        For Each fi In dir1.GetFiles("*.bmp")
            fileList(UBound(fileList)) = fi.Name
            ReDim Preserve fileList(UBound(fileList) + 1)
        Next

        For Each fi In dir1.GetFiles("*.png")
            fileList(UBound(fileList)) = fi.Name
            ReDim Preserve fileList(UBound(fileList) + 1)
        Next

        For Each fi In dir1.GetFiles("*.jpg")
            fileList(UBound(fileList)) = fi.Name
            ReDim Preserve fileList(UBound(fileList) + 1)
        Next

        'Create animation
        anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(UBound(fileList) * 2)

        Dim idx As Integer
        For idx = 0 To UBound(fileList) - 1
            btm(idx) = New BitmapImage(New Uri(txtAddress.Text & "\" & fileList(idx), UriKind.Absolute))
            anim.KeyFrames.Add(New DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(btm(idx), KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(idx * 2))))
            ReDim Preserve btm(UBound(btm) + 1)
        Next

        Dim sBoard As New Storyboard
        sBoard.Children.Add(anim)
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, imgMain.Name)
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, New PropertyPath("imgMain.Source"))
        sBoard.Begin(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Bump - I believe the issue is using a bitmapImage as the object in ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.